# JQuery Read or Modify Dynamically Added Text Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where the user can dynamically add or remove sets of fields. For each set of fields, when the user enters/changes a value in the upc[] text input I want to make an Ajax query and populate the corresponding desc[] text input. I can capture the change event, but have not been able to read or modify the dynamically create desc[] field:

This snippet does not have the Ajax call as for now I just want to know I can set desc[x].val(). I have tried to associate the dynamic field with a parent element that existed when the DOM was created...but still no luck.

```
$(document).on('change', '.upcScan', function(){
  var upcIdx = $(this).index('.upcScan');
  var upcVal = $(this).val();
  alert ("The current index is "+upcIdx+" and the value is "+upcVal);
  var descName = "desc["+upcIdx+"]";
  var descVal = $("#addClient input[name='"+descName+"']").val();
  alert("desc field is "+descName+" and value is "+descVal);
});
```

The code above returns null. If I try to set the val nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Comment: We need to see the html. What is #addClient ? Are you getting correct alert with current index and upcVal? which step is failing? you should go line by line and verify which line is failing.

Comment: #addClient is a the form, which exists when the DOM is created. The alert returns all the correct values except it does not return the desc[] value, nor can I set that value. There are no errors in the console